# Creating an app on the Wear OS watch that receives data from a python script on the desktop every 2-3 seconds. How do I go on doing this?

Tags: java, python, sockets, client-server, wear-os

I have a python script in the desktop that reads telnet modules every 2 seconds using the telnet library and outputs a certain message based on the telnet packets. I want to create an app on the Wear OS that will receive the certain message directly from the Python program at the desktop every 2 seconds and display it. They both are in the same LAN and share the same wifi.

How do I do that and which libraries should I use? There isn't enough documentation online on how to go on and doing that, as far as I know.

My plan is developing a java program for the watch app that uses socket libraries that will receive the message from the python script in the desktop(which also has sockets) at every two seconds. I will use the wifi IP address of the watch in order connect the socket client(PC) and server(Watch).

Is that a good way of moving forward, or am I wasting my time?

Here is the watch that my team is using: [https://www.amazon.com/TicWatch-Bluetooth-Payments-Assistant-Compatible/dp/B07C6S92B8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C6S92B8)

Comment: Just do it, and post the problems if you got some

Comment: Maybe a little help from the [Wear OS documentation](https://developer.android.com/wear/) can also help you go through your project.